# webauthn and screen lock on opera browser

Tags: javascript, api, opera, webauthn

I'm looking to authenticate by finger print. on chrome all is good but on Opera, i have an error

```
The specified userVerification requirement cannot be fulfilled by this device unless the device is secured with a screen lock.
```

I add some extensions with uvi, uvm but i had the same error.

```
authenticatorSelection: { authenticatorAttachment: "platform" }

extensions : { uvi: true, uvm: true }
```

Any help please.

Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the userVerification value to preffered`.

Thank you